# Email alerts from SO contain layout issues on my mobile device

Tags: bug, email, android

Not sure if this is just me, but the StackOverflow emails that I get when I have new comments or whatever consistently have a serious layout problem on my phone.

As soon as I open the message, it goes from length = 2 inches or so, to length = infinity. The scroll bar gets teeny tiny on the right, and all I can see is whitespace. If I scroll down, I can do so seemingly forever without ever seeing any part of the message.

This means that there's no way for me to look at the message, and no way to know which of my questions/comments I'm getting an alert for. I *could* go log into SO on my phone, and check that way, but I *never* log into Google via my phone's browser -- it's just too difficult.

Anyway, some info about the phone:

- Cyanogen 7
- Application seems to just be called, "Email" it's version 2.3.4

Anybody else seeing this, or how do bug reports get handled around these parts?

Comment: Infinite whitespace is not a feature of HTML email, as far as I'm aware.  I think you ought to take this up with the CyanogenMod developers.

Comment: That's weird that it only happens for SO, but I've never personally had any problems with any SE network emails, using CyanogenMod 7.2.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty odd, and it's only the SO emails that have ever done this.

Comment: I'm not equipped to attempt to repro this, but to answer your meta question, you did the correct thing for filing a bug report.

Comment: +1: I have an HTC Evo and experience the exact same issue.